# Classifying a Markov chain and its states

Tags: statistics

I am learning Markov chain by myself and am very new to this concept. I need a help in the following:
Consider a Markov chain with state space {1,....,100}. Suppose states 2i and 2j communicate with each other and states 2i-1 and 2j-1 communicate for all $i,j\in \{1,...,50\} $
Suppose  $p_{3,3}^{(2)}>0$, $p_{4,4}^{(3)}>0$ and $p_{2,5}^{(7)}>0$. Then is the Markov chain irreducible and periodic and are the states 8 and 9 recurrent?
I got the answer that every state in this chain to be recurrent and the chain to be aperiodic and reducible... Am I correct. In general how to approach a problem like this? Any    help please! Also please give me some study material for Markov chain if possible.

Comment: Dmitri Bertsekas' "Data Networks" is a quite famous book and taught in many graduate schools. You can get a free e-copy from MIT's website: http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Queueing_Data_Nets.pdf

Comment: The best approach would be to draw out a portion of the Markov Chain and observe whether it is irreducible, aperiodic and recurrent.

Comment: @an4s Thank you for sharing the link....and yes I'll try it